# Reuse of AWS.SNS service from Node.js AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js

When using the [SNS client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html) found on [AWS-SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk):

```
const sns = new AWS.SNS({});
```

Should I reuse this object across calls to save a handshake with the server?

This kind of object is usually stateless and benefits from pooling/cache; However the docs aren't really clear about that.

Comment: Are you using Lambda?

Comment: @hephalump yes!

Comment: @Scaccoman's answer is the correct answer! He beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks @hephalump!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should initiate the class outside of your lambda. 
AWS will reuse the instance when possible.

E.g.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const sns = new AWS.SNS()

module.exports.handler = async input => {
  // use sns class here
  return input
}
```

**EDIT:**

Link to the official documentation that explains how the lambda execution context works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html

> Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler
>   code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional
>   optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your
>   Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of
>   reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in
>   subsequent invocations. We suggest adding logic in your code to check
>   if a connection exists before creating one.

Comment: That's the guidance I was looking for. Is there an official sample or docs to support this that you know of?

Comment: @BrunoBrant Of course, check this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html

Comment: Also worth reading https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/